# Does the orientation of the adjacency matrix of a digraph matter?

Tags: graph-theory

Consider a digraph $G$ where $U=\{1,2,3,4\}$, $V=\{(1,2),(3,4),(3,2)\}$, then the adjacency matrix is

$$M=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$$

but is it $M$ or $M^T$?

Comment: By convention, your $M$ would be the correct adjacency matrix for your digraph. $M^T$ would be the adjacency matrix for the graph where all the arrows go in the opposite direction. Basically, $M_{ij}=1$ iff $(i,j)\in V$

Comment: The nice convention has the property that if $e_i$ is the vector corresponding to vertex $i$ then $M e_i = \sum_{i \to j} e_j$ where the sum is over all arrows pointing out from $i$. So it's whichever one has that property. But it is a convention.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan What do you mean by the vertex corresponding to $i$, the unit vector which the 1-entry is in the $i$-th position? Also, I don't understand the $i\to j$ notation, what are you summing over?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan : Actually, it's backwards -- $M$ encodes the "comes from" relation.  $M \cdot e_i$ gives the indicator vector for vertices having edges to $i$.  Much like reversing the charge convention, when I have a time machine...

Comment: Really? That's not the convention I would use.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Me neither.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an adjacency matrix, $a_{i,j} = 1$ if and only if there is an edge from vertex $i$ to vertex $j$.  $i$ is the row and $j$ is the column.

Consequently, if $(1,2)$ is an edge, $a_{1,2} = 1$, which is the case for your $M$.

Comment: Why $a_{i,j}$ instead of $a_{j,i}$?

Comment: @Garmekain Convention. The same thing happens for Markov chains.

Comment: Because that would be an edge in the opposite direction.  It's a convention.  Why is clockwise not the other way around?